# How to make Sliding up Panel city circular from only one side FLUTTER

Tags: flutter

[I'm a beginner and want to make Sliding up Panel like this. Your help will be appreciated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oB4l.jpg)

Comment: Have a stack. In the stack 2 containers: one is a big white that is on the bottom side, one rounded that goes on top of that and use positioned to set it where it should go.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
  GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(15.0)),
          ),
          builder: (context) {
            return Stack(
              overflow: Overflow.visible,
              children: [
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: List<Widget>.generate(
                    10,
                    (int index) => ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.email, color: Colors.black),
                      title: Text('$index',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                      onTap: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: -50,
                  left: 20,
                  child: ClipOval(child: Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),)
                ),
              ],
            );
          });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will get you what you want:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() => runApp(const MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return const MaterialApp(
          title: _title,
          home: MyStatelessWidget(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: 
          Stack(
            children: [
              Center(
                child: Container(
                    height: 300,
                    width: 300,
                    child: Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topRight: Radius.circular(50),
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(50))),
                    )),
              ),
              Positioned(
// You can change top and left values based on the layout or device
                top: 140,
                left: 70,
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  child: Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 20,
                              backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                  'https://icon-library.com/images/avatar-icon-images/avatar-icon-images-4.jpg')),
                          Text('Patrick')
                        ],
                      )),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

[image]